# Why does the same batch file not work on multiple computers?

Tags: batch-file

I've made this batch file at home:

```
@echo off
set src_folder=E:\1
set dst_folder=E:\3
set file_list=E:\File-list.txt

   if not exist "%dst_folder%" mkdir "%dst_folder%"

for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) do (
echo "No" | xcopy "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\"
)
```

But when I've tryed to use it on my computer at work it stated that the file/s could not be found.
What's the catch?
First I've tryed to use it for shared files on a mapped drive, I trough it was because of that. But I've tried it on multiple workstations/computers at work and on a few of them it worked. Can someone explain this?

Note:

- I've had to change the folder location each time since it's not the same on all computers.
- I've also used `%~dp0` for the file-list.

Comment: Is your source folder (src_folder) exists on every work station ? check that , it might be the reason why your for loop is getting skipped

Comment: not it does not, so I had to change the location each time.

Comment: There is a missing quotation mark at the end of the script. Copy paste error to SO, or real error in the script?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out , it was actualy a copy paste error, the batch file has the quotation mark .

Comment: If `%src_folder%` contains spaces, add quotation marks in the `if` condition.

Comment: Because my english is lackying Im unable to understand where the quotation marks should be, could you be so kind and point out exaclty the part where I should add them , a little more details..
Im guesting in the case where the location looks like this 
set dst_folder=F:\Tarlale\L\Bez M

Comment: Then you need `for %%f in ("%src_folder%\*") do ...` . Otherwise, it looks like `for %%f in (F:\Tarlale\L\Bez M\*) do ...` which means look for a file called `F:\Tarlale\L\Bez` and then look for any files in `M\*`. Obviously that is not what you intend.

Comment: What is the content and format/structure of `File-list.txt`?

Comment: File name plus file extension , example : 123.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `File-list.txt` containing only single file names of the type `filename.ext` *(without paths but spaces are allowed)* on each line:

```bat
@Echo Off
REM Place your source destination and file list paths below
REM Remember not to remove the closing double quotation mark
Set "srcDir=E:\1"
Set "dstDir=E:\3"
Set "lstTxt=E:\File-list.txt"

REM Exit the script if no source or destination 
REM or if unable to change directory to that destination
If Not Exist "%srcDir%\" Exit/B
If Not Exist "%dstDir%\" MD "%dstDir%">Nul||Exit/B
CD /D "%dstDir%" 2>Nul||Exit/B

REM Copies any files within the file list existing in source
REM to the current directory which is the intended destination
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%lstTxt%"
) Do If Exist "%srcDir%\%%~A" Copy /Y "%srcDir%\%%~A">Nul
```

Your `File-list.txt` can look like this:

```
file name.ext
another.txt
```

Or like this:

```
"file name.txt"
another.ext
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on where the exact place of quotation mark should be. also your code works like a charm for my needs, now I just need to understand each part of it so that I can use it on future projects*

Comment: I have added some REMarks in order to help you a little with that. If you feel that your initial question has now been answered then please mark the answer as accepted.